# I want the row to keep the correct class

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I use this for the row colors:

```
 echo"<tr class=\"normal\" onClick=\"this.className='normalselected'\" 
           onmouseover=\"this.className='normalon'\" 
           onmouseout=\"this.className='normal'\">\n";
```

It works when you move over, it works when you click only when I move to another row it goes back to normal.

How can I change this?

Comment: Escape orgies, yuck! Did you know that you can also use single quotes in PHP/HTML? Besides that, hover styling shouldn't be done using JavaScript but with the `:hover` css pseudo-class.

Comment: how is this a php question? I edited to remove the php tag and added javascript.. hope that is ok..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because onmouseout put's it back to normal; what you need is to remember when you clicked. although this is not a "nice" solution it should do what you want

In your css

```
.normal-clicked,
.normal-over { 
     /* whatever needs to go here */
}
.normal {
     /* whatever needs to go here */
}
```

Then in the php

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleClick( el ){
        if ( el.className == 'normal-clicked' ){
            el.className = 'normal';
        }
        else {
            el.className = 'normal-clicked';
        }
    }
    function handleMouseOver( el ){
        el.className = 'normal-over';
    }
    function handleMouseOut( el ){
        if ( el.className == 'normal-over' ){
            el.className = 'normal';
        }
    }
</script>
<?php
echo '<tr class="normal" onclick="handleClick(this);" onmouseover="handleMouseOver(this);" onmouseout="handleMouseOut(this);">', "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<tr class=\"normal\" onclick=\"this.className='normalselected'\" 
       onmouseover=\"if (!/normalselected/gi.test(this.className)) this.className='normalon'\" 
       onmouseout=\"if (!/normalselected/gi.test(this.className)) this.className='normal'\">\n";
```

Though I would seriously consider using CSS hover, and proper event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

even if I don't agree to the way you did this, just to answer your question: you are removing the normalselected class on the mouseout event, that's normal. you can prevent that just by adding a condition like

```
if('normalon' == this.className)
```

to your mouseout event handler

also you might want to prevent adding the normalon class when you come again over an already selected row.. so you would need to add something like

```
if('normal' == this.className)
```

to your onmouseover attribute.. but you should really consider using a function instead of all those conditions if you plan to stick with javascript for this